# how to overloading without arithematic operator

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Expression
{
    private :
    double val;

    public :

    Expression() : val(0)
    {

    }


    Expression(double v) : val(v)
    {

    }


    Expression operator +(Expression a)
    {
        Expression a1;
        a1.val = val + a.val;
        return a1;
    }

    Expression operator --()
    {
        Expression temp1;
        temp1.val = --val;
        return temp1;
    }
    Expression operator --(int)
    {
        return Expression(val--);
    }

    Expression operator * (Expression b1)
    {
        Expression b;
        b.val = val * b1.val; 
        return b;
    }

    double showvalue()
    {
        return val;
    }


};

int main()
{
    Expression E1;
    Expression E2(5.5) , E3;
    E3(2.0);

    cout << E3.showvalue();
    cout << endl;
    Expression E4;

    E4 = E3;
    E1 = E2+--E3*E4--;
    cout << E1.showvalue();
    return 0;
}
```

In the main where I have E3(2.0)

How would I overload so it would work without doing, Expression E3(2.0);
just E3(2.0);
Our teacher says there is a way to do this, so I want to know it
Again
I want it to be only E3(2.0) or any value inside, so it works
(filling so I can post
don't read this just adding details for no reason beacasue it says so)

Comment: Implement `Expression Expression::operator()(double)`

Comment: Yes indeed, the compiler said the same

Can you elaborate it a little more

Comment: By the way, that whole bit of your question where you say "don't read this" _was_ the important part of your question.  If you thought we could deduce what you were trying to achieve without actually describing it, you are fooling yourself.  The semantics you're aiming for are quite unusual, and not standard practice for something like this.

Comment: What `E3(2.0);` suppose to do? It is like `3.0(2.0)` and I have no idea what to expect from that. Looks like you misunderstood your task. `Expression` says it suppose to be an expression, but it represents a value, so for me this is another indicator that you do not know what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

You might have `operator()` acting as assigment.

```
class Expression
{
public:
    Expression& operator=(double d) { val = d; return *this; }
    void operator()(double d) { *this = d; }
// ...
};
```